# assertEqual only shows differences

Tags: unit-testing, python-2.7, assert

In Python 2.7, I use `assertEqual` for comparing two strings.

But in some cases I have very long strings, and I would like `assertEqual` to show only the differences and not the full strings.

For this, I use `difflib`, like that

```
    import difflib
    #...
    diff = difflib.unified_diff(
        string1.splitlines(True),
        string2.splitlines(True),
        n=0
    )

    diff = ''.join(diff)

    self.assertEqual('', diff, msg=diff)
```

Is there some `assert*` method doing that?

Comment: So, you're just wondering if there's an `assert*` method built into `unitttest` that does what you ended up doing manually?

Comment: @dano, yes, this is my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [`assertMultiLineEqual`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertMultiLineEqual), which will print out a diff of the strings *in addition* to the complete strings:

```
import unittest
import difflib

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_a(self):
        a = """hi
there
ok"""
        b = """bye
there
ok
whatever"""
        self.assertMultiLineEqual(a,b)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Output:

```
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_a (__main__.MyTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ut.py", line 27, in test_a
    self.assertMultiLineEqual(a,b)
AssertionError: 'hi\nthere\nok' != 'bye\nthere\nok\nwhatever'
- hi
+ bye
  there
- ok+ ok
?   +
+ whatever

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

According to the docs, this is actually supposed to be automatically called when you call `assertEqual` with string arguments, but it is actually only called if you pass in *unicode* strings. You can fix this by using the `addTypeEqualityFunc` to register the `str` type with `assertMutiLineEqual`. Then all your test cases can just use `assertEqual`, and will still get the diff behavior:

```
import unittest

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyTestCase, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.addTypeEqualityFunc(str, self.assertMultiLineEqual)

    def test_a(self):
        a = """hi
there
ok"""
        b = """bye
there
ok
whatever"""
        self.assertEqual(a,b)  # Will actually call self.assertMultiLineEqual

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

If you *only* want to see the diff, rather than the complete string in addition to the diff, you could sub-class `unittest.TestCase` and add an assertion method that does the desired formatting:

```
import unittest
import difflib

class _BaseTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyTestCase, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.addTypeEqualityFunc(str, self.assertEqualWithDiff)

    def assertEqualWithDiff(self, left, right, msg=None):
        try:
            self._baseAssertEqual(left, right)
        except self.failureException:
            diff = difflib.unified_diff(
                left.splitlines(True),
                right.splitlines(True),
                n=0 
            )   
            diff = ''.join(diff)
            raise self.failureException("\n" + diff)

class MyTestCase(_BaseTestCase):   
    def test_a(self):
        a = """hi
there
ok"""
        b = """bye
there
ok
whatever"""
        self.assertEqual(a,b)  # This will actually call assertEqualWithDiff    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Output:

```
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_a (__main__.MyTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ut.py", line 26, in test_a
    self.assertEqualWithDiff(a,b)
  File "ut.py", line 15, in assertEqualWithDiff
    raise self.failureException("\n" + diff)
AssertionError: 
--- 
+++ 
@@ -1 +1 @@
-hi
+bye
@@ -3 +3,2 @@
-ok+ok
+whatever

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Comment: The key note buried in the answer above is, "it is actually only called if you pass in unicode strings."  Thanks!